# How can I animate the Expo-blur View intensity using react-native-reanimated?

Tags: react-native, expo, blur, react-native-reanimated

I use React native and Expo and in the latest version of SDK 49, they mentioned that we can animate BlurView intensity with react-native-reanimated. The problem is that it doesn't work.

**THis is My HomeScreen in Which there is the ScrollView**

```
import { Dimensions, View } from "react-native";
import Animated, {
  useAnimatedScrollHandler,
  useSharedValue,
} from "react-native-reanimated";

const { height } = Dimensions.get("window");


const HomeScreen = () => {
  const scrollOffset = useSharedValue(0);
  const scrollHandler = useAnimatedScrollHandler({
    onScroll: (event) => {
      scrollOffset.value = event.contentOffset.y;
    },
  });

  return (
    <View className="flex-1 bg-white">
      <View className="absolute w-full z-10">
        <Headerbar scrollOffset={scrollOffset} />
      </View>
      <Animated.ScrollView
        onScroll={scrollHandler}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        snapToAlignment={"start"}
        snapToInterval={height * 0.22}
        decelerationRate={"fast"}
      >
        <Header scrollOffset={scrollOffset} />
        <View className="pt-5 pb-2 rounded-t-2xl -mt-4 bg-white">
          <CategoryList />
        </View>
        <View className="py-5 bg-[#F7F7F7] rounded-t-2xl">
          <BestSales />
        </View>
      </Animated.ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
```

**THis is My Header in which there is the BlurView I want to animate**

```
import { BlurView } from "expo-blur";
import React from "react";
import { Text, TouchableNativeFeedback, View } from "react-native";
import {
  Extrapolation,
  SharedValue,
  interpolate,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from "react-native-safe-area-context";


const Headerbar: React.FC<HeaderbarProps> = ({ scrollOffset }) => {
  const { top } = useSafeAreaInsets();

  const blurIntensity = interpolate(
    scrollOffset.value,
    [0, 172],
    [0, 50],
    Extrapolation.CLAMP
  );

  return (
    <BlurView intensity={blurIntensity} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View
        style={[
          {
            paddingTop: top * 1.2,
            paddingBottom: top * 0.4,
            paddingHorizontal: 16,
          },
        ]}
      />
    </BlurView>
 )
```

What is my Bad?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution,

**By default, BlurView is not animatable** (*I thought it was by default*). So to animate BlurView with **react-native-reanimated** you need to create the AnimatedBlurView component with `Animated.createAnimatedComponent(BlurView)` but with that you can't animate at this stage. The last step is to create animatedProps with **useAnimatedProps** and pass them as props to AnimatedBlurView

```
const App = ()=>{
    const AnimatedBlurView = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(BlurView);

    const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
        const intensity = interpolate(
          scrollY.value,
          [0, 150, 172],
          [0, 0, 50],
          Extrapolation.CLAMP
        );
    
        return {
          intensity,
        };
  });
    
  return (
    <AnimatedBlurView animatedProps={animatedProps} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View
        style={{
          paddingTop: top * 1.2,
          paddingBottom: top * 0.4,
          paddingHorizontal: 16,
        }}
      >
    </AnimatedBlurView>
  )  


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-animated-blur-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-blur-view) library to animate blur view intensity.

Just pass `blurStart`, `blurEnd`, `animationDuration` properties and call `start` method via ref to start the animation. This one works smoother then https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-blur library. The native blur effect view sometimes adds a white overlay event if the blur amount is 1.

e.g

```
const blurViewRef = useRef<AnimatedBlurViewMethods>();

  useEffect(() => {
    blurViewRef.current?.start(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>React Native Animated Blur View</Text>
      <AnimatedBlurView
        ref={blurViewRef}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
        blurStart={10}
        blurEnd={20}
        animationDuration={2}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

It also supports a `gradient` option.